# Скрытие уведомления и остановка работы Location Manager при выключении навигатора

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

Хочу повторить логику Google Map. Когда использую навигатор, нужно обновлять карту в `background`. Для этого использую `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`, и у меня появляется синяя шапка, которая говорит, что программа использует локацию:

[image: локация]

Когда человек выключил навигатор, мне нет смысла отслеживать его передвижение. Как мне убрать эту синюю шапку и остановить работу `Location Manager` в `background`?

Когда навигатор не работает, мне нужно, чтобы локация обновлялась, только когда приложение активно.

Программу пишу на *Swift*, но *Objective-C* тоже знаю, так что можно это сделать на любом из этих языков.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно в контроллере получить уведомление, о том, что приложение свернуто. Это часть показана тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25716012/triggering-a-specific-action-when-the-app-enters-foreground-from-a-local-notifi

В **AppDelegate** добавить 2 обработчика

```
func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.


    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

    }
```